# NanoStringDiff produces very large logFC values

Tags: r

I am trying to use NanoStringDiff to identify differentially expressed microRNAs between treatment and control samples, but I am obtaining extraordinarily large values for the fold change (log2FC is 27 for certain genes, but expected to be around 1 by inspection). I think there is an error with my code. I am using the following guide http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/NanoStringDiff/inst/doc/NanoStringDiff.pdf
I've included my code below and the data I am using is publicly available on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE84971 (GSE84971_non-normalized.txt.gz)
I took this data and converted it into an Excel file in the format as specified in the guide which I called "data".

Any help is much appreciated.

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("NanoStringDiff")
biocLite("Biobase")
library("BioBase") 
library("NanoStringDiff")

designs=data.frame(group=c("Control","Control","Control", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Treatment"))
designs 

directory <- "/Users/admin/Desktop" 

path <- paste(directory, "data.csv", sep ="/", collapse = NULL) 
NanoStringData=createNanoStringSetFromCsv(path,header=TRUE,designs)  

pheno=pData(NanoStringData)
group=pheno$group
design.full=model.matrix(~0+group) #create a design (or model) matrix
design.full

contrast=c(-1,1) 

NanoStringData=estNormalizationFactors(NanoStringData) 

positiveFactor(NanoStringData)
negativeFactor(NanoStringData)
housekeepingFactor(NanoStringData)

result=glm.LRT(NanoStringData,design.full, Beta= ncol(design.full), contrast=contrast)
result$table
```

I attempted to add the data using dput(NanoString), hopefully this makes my code more self-contained. Below is shown the output.

```
new("NanoStringSet"
    , positiveFactor = numeric(0)
    , negativeFactor = numeric(0)
    , housekeepingFactor = numeric(0)
    , positiveControl = structure(c(51117L, 9153L, 2357L, 749L, 133L, 88L, 30283L, 6423L,
                                    1178L, 444L, 83L, 35L, 46143L, 8040L, 2014L, 554L, 114L, 82L,
                                    48365L, 9338L, 2158L, 603L, 135L, 91L, 52744L, 10177L, 2391L,
                                    786L, 143L, 72L, 70189L, 12069L, 3186L, 693L, 176L, 110L), .Dim = c(6L,
                                                                                                        6L), .Dimnames = list(c("POS_A(128)", "POS_B(32)", "POS_C(8)",
                                                                                                                                "POS_D(2)", "POS_E(0.5)", "POS_F(0.125)"), c("Control.1", "Control.2",
                                                                                                                                                                             "Control.3", "Treatment.1", "Treatment.2", "Treatment.3")))
    , negativeControl = structure(c(52L, 32L, 40L, 14L, 104L, 74L, 28L, 25L, 29L, 11L,
                                    74L, 45L, 31L, 32L, 29L, 13L, 80L, 60L, 61L, 44L, 32L, 5L, 103L,
                                    74L, 56L, 42L, 44L, 15L, 135L, 62L, 55L, 54L, 36L, 12L, 108L,
                                    61L), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("NEG_B(0)", "NEG_C(0)",
                                                                               "NEG_A(0)", "NEG_F(0)", "NEG_E(0)", "NEG_D(0)"), c("Control.1",
                                                                                                                                  "Control.2", "Control.3", "Treatment.1", "Treatment.2", "Treatment.3"
                                                                               )))
    , housekeepingControl = structure(c(825L, 1892L, 1293L, 1496L, 2157L, 1254L, 1081L, 1121L,
                                        914L, 1223L, 2123L, 3912L, 1876L, 2217L, 3363L, 1392L, 1750L,
                                        1626L, 1196L, 1917L, 1378L, 1446L, 1300L, 1077L, 1875L, 2098L,
                                        8006L, 2989L, 4447L, 4930L), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(c("Actb|0",
                                                                                                    "B2m|0", "Gapdh|0", "Rpl19|0", "Rplp0|0"), c("Control.1", "Control.2",
                                                                                                                                                 "Control.3", "Treatment.1", "Treatment.2", "Treatment.3")))
    , experimentData = new("MIAME"
                           , name = ""
                           , lab = ""
                           , contact = ""
                           , title = ""
                           , abstract = ""
                           , url = ""
                           , pubMedIds = ""
                           , samples = list()
                           , hybridizations = list()
                           , normControls = list()
                           , preprocessing = list()
                           , other = list()
                           , .__classVersion__ = new("Versions"
                                                     , .Data = list(c(1L, 0L, 0L), c(1L, 1L, 0L))
                           )
    )
    , assayData = <environment>
      , phenoData = new("AnnotatedDataFrame"
                        , varMetadata = structure(list(labelDescription = NA_character_), .Names = "labelDescription", row.names = "group", class = "data.frame")
                        , data = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Control",
                                                                                                        "Treatment"), class = "factor")), .Names = "group", row.names = c("Control.1",
                                                                                                                                                                          "Control.2", "Control.3", "Treatment.1", "Treatment.2", "Treatment.3"
                                                                                                        ), class = "data.frame")
                        , dimLabels = c("sampleNames", "sampleColumns")
                        , .__classVersion__ = new("Versions"
                                                  , .Data = list(c(1L, 1L, 0L))
                        )
      )
    , featureData = new("AnnotatedDataFrame"
                        , varMetadata = structure(list(labelDescription = character(0)), .Names = "labelDescription", row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame")
                        , data = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("hsa-miR-10a-5p|0",
                                                                                                              "hsa-miR-1234|0", "hsa-miR-185-5p|0", "hsa-miR-27a-3p", "hsa-miR-34c-3p",
                                                                                                              "hsa-miR-1181|0", "hsa-miR-601", "hsa-miR-4454"))
                        , dimLabels = c("featureNames", "featureColumns")
                        , .__classVersion__ = new("Versions"
                                                  , .Data = list(c(1L, 1L, 0L))
                        )
    )
    , annotation = character(0)
    , protocolData = new("AnnotatedDataFrame"
                         , varMetadata = structure(list(labelDescription = character(0)), .Names = "labelDescription", row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame")
                         , data = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Control.1",
                                                                                                               "Control.2", "Control.3", "Treatment.1", "Treatment.2", "Treatment.3"
                         ))
                         , dimLabels = c("sampleNames", "sampleColumns")
                         , .__classVersion__ = new("Versions"
                                                   , .Data = list(c(1L, 1L, 0L))
                         )
    )
    , .__classVersion__ = new("Versions"
                              , .Data = list(c(3L, 3L, 1L), c(2L, 34L, 0L), c(1L, 3L, 0L), c(1L, 0L,
                                                                                             0L))
    )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is well written considering that it is your first question. However, at Stack Overflow we request that your example is not only reproducible, but also self-contained and *minimal*. For the `r` tag we further ask that you share the data via `dput()` for better reproducibility. Asides avoiding problems like the one I'm having now trying to figure out which file you used it also avoids the question becoming useless when the link no longer works.

Comment: Dear Hack-R, many thanks for your reply and helpful tips! I've now added the data using dput() to my code, hopefully this will make it easier to work with.

Comment: I observed the same issue:
among 700+ genes, I found 4 genes whose DE are very high(+/-) however they should close to zero by inspection